# Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha - Improper alignment using input with add-on within card

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm placing an `input` with a `.input-group-addon` within a card. The add-on and text input area seem to get centered in it's parents container, and have unnecessary space around them. I tried just about everything, using utility classes to strip padding, margin, and set floats, but nothing works. Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image]

```
<div class="card-deck-wrapper">
    <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
                <p class="card-text">

                <label class="checkbox-inline" for="cb">
                <input type="checkbox" id="cb" name="cb" value="Y">Checkbox</label>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fld" id="fld" disabled>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<p class="card-text">` Where's the closing `</p>` tag?

Comment: Fixed example. I do have a closing </p> tag.

Comment: You are using _alpha software_ which means you shouldn't be trying to make something with it without expecting strange things to happen.

Comment: I'm not sure of a solution to this, but @Fiskie brings up a valid point. Consider submitting this question to https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues and see if the devs can look into it more there.